# Signing ZIP file using Java programmatically

Tags: java

I used ZipOutputStream for creating ZIP file but I also need to programatically encrypt this using public key. Can someone provide if there is a Java library that can be used for this?

Comment: I need to use public key for encryption as the files are compressed at customer site. And once we receive the files, we should be able to decrypt using private key. Asymmetric keys can be used either way and I am looking for Java API to do the same programmatically that we otherwise do using genkeypair, keytool and jarsigner.

Comment: @Robby See this article.  http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/#p9 maybe you're speaking in a different context. But for PGP, for instance, you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key. The idea is that only the intended recipient, who holds the private key, (not the public) can read the data.

Comment: @BenArunski I had already realized the errors of my ways. I misread encrypt for sign. Thanks for the clarification anyway.

Comment: Robby, can you up vote it as question is valid. No big deal but why have a point down for no reason :-).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should fill your need. http://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/